# Inserção de 1000 registros em tabela com uniqueidentifier como chave primária

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho que adicionar, **1000**  registros em uma determinada tabela. Ela contem o Campo `Name`.

Tenho o Script, que faz a inserção em massa. Porém, a chave primária desta tabela, é um `uniqueidentifier`(`Guid()`) como eu posso fazer isso usando esta abordagem.

Segue o script para a criação com chave primária `int`

```
declare @id int 
select @id = 1
while @id >=1 and @id <= 1000
begin
    insert into client values(@id, 'jack' + convert(varchar(5), @id), 12)
    select @id = @id + 1
end
```

Comment: Não é melhor você setar o `id` como `identity` na sua tabela?

Comment: @Sorack, na real como ele é um uniqueidentifier, pensei não ter a necessidade.

Answer (score 4):

Use a função [NewId()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190348.aspx)

```
declare @contador int 
select @contador = 1
while @contador >=1 and @contador <= 1000
begin
    insert into client values (NewId(), 'jack' + convert(varchar(5), @contador), 12)
    select @contador = @contador + 1
end
```

---

Uma observação importante é que se a tabela tiver **mais de duas colunas** o `Insert` precisa especificar as colunas que estão sendo inseridas.

Algo como

```
Insert Into (Id, Nome) Values (NewId(), 'Jack');
```

Answer (score 1):

Eis sugestão para inclusão das linhas utilizando uma única execução do INSERT na tabela. Em geral, é mais eficiente.

```
-- código #1
INSERT into client (col1, col2, col3)
  SELECT NewId(), ('jack ' + convert(varchar(5), N.Número)), 12
    from tbNúmero as N
    where N.Número <= 1000;
go
```

---

A tabela tbNúmero é uma tabela permanente, tendo sido criada previamente.

```
-- código #2
-- tabela auxiliar de números
CREATE TABLE tbNúmero (Número int);

declare @max int, @rc int;
set @max= 100000;
set @rc= 1;
set nocount on;
INSERT into tbNúmero(Número) values (1);
while (@rc * 2 <= @max)
   begin 
   INSERT into tbNúmero(Número) SELECT (Número + @rc) from tbNúmero;
   set @rc = @rc * 2;
   end;
INSERT into tbNúmero(Número)
   SELECT (Número + @rc) from tbNúmero where (Número + @rc) <= @max;
go
```

Fonte: Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Querying, de Itzik Ben-gan

---

Documentação diretamente relacionada:

- [uniqueidentifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187942.aspx)
- [NewID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190348.aspx)